# Create path constraints and dump as a .sqlite file in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, motion-planning, path-planning

I am trying to define path constraints in the "MotionPlanning" window on Moveit using RViz in ROS Iron. Using [panda_test_db.sqlite](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/cfcd9598977419fb977a4460a0ed7981c13642d0/doc/how_to_guides/parallel_planning/config/panda_test_db.sqlite), I connected to the database successfully. I could see the scenes in RViz as shown below:

[image]

However, my objective is to use path constraints (such as keeping the end-effector's Orientation vertical) via RViz. It seems that the "Planning" tab can load these constraints from a given database. See below the highlighted region on the screenshot, please:

[image]

Unfortunately, [the documentation on persistent scenes](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/how_to_guides/persistent_scenes_and_states/persistent_scenes_and_states.html) isn't very helpful in this regard. Nevertheless, how do you define path constraints and dump them as a .sqlite file?